# How to calculate end of the month in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

How to calculate end of the month in Postgres? I have table with column date datatype. I want to calculate end of the month of every date. For Eg. In the table there values like "2015-07-10 17:52:51","2015-05-30 11:30:19" then end of the month should be like 31 July 2015,31 May 2015.
Please guide me in this.

Answer (score 10):

How about truncating to the beginning of this month, jumping forward one month, then back one day?

```
=#  select (date_trunc('month', now()) + interval '1 month - 1 day')::date;
date
------------
 2015-07-31
(1 row)
```

Change `now()` to your date variable, which must be a timestamp, per [the docs](http://postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html). You can then manipulate this output (with `strftime`, etc.) to any format you need.

[Source](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Date_LastDay)

Comment: Um, that's not right...  That's the first of the next month.  Try select (date_trunc('month', '2015-06-01'::date)::date + interval '1 month - 1 day')::date;

Comment: This doesn't work if you have a date like '2014-01-01'.

Comment: @LunchBox correct. The second argument to `date_trunc` must be a timestamp, according to the docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html. `date_trunc('MONTH', timestamp '2014-01-01')` would fit with that example.

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT TO_CHAR(
    DATE_TRUNC('month', CURRENT_DATE)  
      + INTERVAL '1 month'            
      - INTERVAL '1 day',              
    'YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS'              
  ) endOfTheMonth
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I tried like this and it worked

```
Date(to_char(date_trunc('month'::text, msm013.msa011) + '1 mon - 1 day '::interval , 'DD-MON-YYYY') )
```

Thanks a lot!!